# Seamlessly hosting different parts of a website in different docker containers

Tags: apache, tomcat, docker, docker-compose

I have a website that I am trying to convert to a docker-compose solution.

Part of the website is a CMS (WordPress, specifically), and there are also a few Java web applications that are currently handled by tomcat.

The current approach is that I have an official WordPress container and an official Tomcat container. I load my custom content in the WordPress (via a MySQL container which is not really a part of this question) and the WAR files into tomcat.

So the problem is this:
Parts of the WordPress website have links to Java applications. Previously, some of these links were relative links as simple as `/Application1` and the user would be able to access the Java application.

Now, since they are hosted in separate containers, I cannot do this because there is nothing named "Application1" in the WordPress container. I have modified the htaccess file for the WordPress container with a RewriteRules like this:

```
# Tomcat exposes port 8085
RewriteRule ^.*Application1/(.*)$ http://localhost:8085/Application1/$1 [R,L]
```

But this means that if the user clicks the link for Application1 in wordpress, their browser will then redirect them to `localhost:8085` - which works fine if you run this set of containers locally, but does not work for remote users.

I could change `localhost` to the actual name of the server this will run on. But then it would need to be manually updated for every server this stack will run on, or reset to localhost for developers.

I could combine WordPress and Tomcat into a single container, but we were hoping to keep them separate so that when we need to upgrade, we just change the version of the container we are pulling rather than having to rebuild a custom container from scratch.

Is there a more seamless way to do this, so that the URL in the user's browser never changes? Is there way to get this working so that remote users won't even know that the different parts of the site are hosted in different containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out: I should have been using a proxy instead of a RewriteRule.

This seems to get me what I want:

```
ProxyPass "/Application1" "http://my-tomcat-server:8080/Application1"
ProxyPassReverse "/Application1" "http://my-tomcat-server:8080/Application1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do docker-compose in development and also in production, you replace `localhost` with `servicename` of the corresponding upstream.

Lets say, you have 3 containers: httpd, fpm ( wordpress) and java ( tomcat ). You configure httpd, to redirect to `fpm:9000` if its domain.tld/php and redirect to `java:8086` if the request is domain.tld/Application1.

All you need to understand is, that the actual service-name you have in docker-compose is available as a hostname in the container ( all containers ) - so containers can reach themselfs using the service-name of the other container - that makes inter-container communication very easy and pre-configureable, without knowing the actual container IPs ( which will change during development / production and host migrations )